# oop js + $.ajax passing variables to father class

Tags: javascript, ajax, oop

I am trying to pass variables from an xml file to the father class in js:
the code is basically OOP js. 
The class is example and the method is getData().

the thing is that the ajax call doesn't return the whole values, just the int ones.. weird, I know.

(changed due to T.J. Crowder:)

```
function example(){
    this.b;
    this.str;
}
example.prototype ={
    getData:function(){
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "Bar.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                            context: this,
                success: function(xml) {
                    this.b = parseInt($(xml).find('current_madad').text()); //int_from_xml- works!
                           this.str = $(xml).find('graph_title').text(); //string_from_xml - doesnt work!!
            }
        })//end ajax    
    }
};

var c = new example();
c.getData();
```

the xml file is here. Posted so that you can review that code as well..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Bars>
    <Bar>
      <bar_start>1010</bar_start>
      <lower_danger_zone>1030</lower_danger_zone>
      <mid_safe_zone>1050</mid_safe_zone>
      <upper_danger_zone>1150</upper_danger_zone>
      <upper_fbdn_zone>1200</upper_fbdn_zone>
      <bar_range>200</bar_range>
      <ideal_range>5</ideal_range>
      <current_madad>1115</current_madad>
    </Bar>
  </Bars>
  <Bars_Desc>
    <Bar>
      <graph_title>פוזיצית אפריל</graph_title>
      <lower_fbdn_zone_Desc>תחום אסור תחתון תיאור</lower_fbdn_zone_Desc>
      <lower_danger_zone_Desc>תחום מסוכן תחתון תיאור</lower_danger_zone_Desc>
      <mid_safe_zone_Desc>תחום בטוח אמצעי תיאור</mid_safe_zone_Desc>
      <mid_safe_ideal_zone_Desc>תחום בטוח פקיעה אידיאלית תיאור</mid_safe_ideal_zone_Desc>
      <upper_danger_zone_Desc>תחום מסוכן עליון תיאור</upper_danger_zone_Desc>
      <upper_fbdn_zone_Desc>תחום אסור עליון תיאור</upper_fbdn_zone_Desc>
    </Bar>
  </Bars_Desc>
</root>
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: where is the "father" class, there is just a single class that doesn't appear to extend anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it! I am using the data I need and passing it throw a function **inside** ajax's success!
getData:function(){

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Bar.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        context: this,     // <=== Set `context` - this helped me BTW
        success: function(xml) {
           arr.f1 = 1;    // 
           arr.f2 = 876;
           pass_data_to_data_handler_function(arr); //<= so I am waiting for response

})//end ajax
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call is *asynchronous*. `getData` *starts* the call, but it completes later, after `getData` has returned, so when you're assigning to `this.b`, `a` hasn't been set by the success callback yet. You need to change your `getData` call:

```
getData:function(){
    var self = this;           // <=== Set up a reference to `this`
    alert("functionlasdkfj");
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Bar.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                self.b = 1;    // <=== Use it to set `b` directly
        }
    })//end ajax
}
```

Or alternately, you can use the `context` option of `ajax` to change what `this` will be in the callback:

```
getData:function(){
    alert("functionlasdkfj");
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Bar.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            context: this,     // <=== Set `context`
            success: function(xml) {
                this.b = 1;    // <=== Now you can set `b` directly
        }
    })//end ajax
}
```

---

Two side notes for you:

1. Re:

   ```
   function example(){
       this.b;
   }
   ```

   The `this.b` stuff there has no effect whatsoever. It's effectively a comment. In particular, it doesn't create a property called `b` on the object.
2. In your original code, unless you declared `a` somewhere, you were falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Comment: Ok, I've used it and it passes the values to the class on the second call(I set up an interval so the data will be refreshed). but it only pulls the integer data and not the stirngs! tried everything... weird no?

Comment: @user1392330: That suggests that there is no `graph_title` XML node in your XML.

Comment: 1. I have a graph_title in my xml . 2. when I removed the this.b I got errored not defined On this.b = xml_data...

Comment: @user1392330: Re 1: Post the XML to your question, and ideally show a complete working example on http://jsbin.com. I can't see how the one would work when the other doesn't. 2. No, sorry, something *else* might be going on, but removing the completely-unnecessary `this.b;` line from your constructor function did not make that line in the `ajax` success callback fail. Not in JavaScript.

Comment: 1 .poseted..  jsbin.com can't include xml file.. can it?

Comment: anyway- I've got it!!. just using a call to another function from with inside the ajax's success!!